# Repository Pattern - Remove child elements from multiple parents

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern

I have the following tables

```
   Public Class Tag

    <Key()> _
    Public Property TagID As Integer

    Public Property Reference As Integer
    Public Property Name As String

    ' Public Overridable Property Tags As ICollection(Of Tag) 
    Public Overridable Property ParentTag As Tag
    Public Overridable Property TagReferences As ICollection(Of TagReference)
End Class


Public Class TagReference
    <Key()> _
    Public Property TagReferenceID As Integer
    Public Property ReferencedID As Integer
    Public Overridable Property Tag As Tag
End Class
```

Now i know 2 values: 
Table: Tag {Reference}
Table: TagReference {ReferenceID}

I implemented the repository pattern.

Now i have a list of Tags which contain the right TagReferences, but the tags may not be deleted, it's the TagReferences.

```
   Variabels = ReferenceValue,ReferenceID

   IEnumerable(Of Tag) =  TagRepository.GetMany(Function(el) el.Reference = ReferenceValue And el.TagReferences.Any(Function(bl) bl.ReferencedID.Equals(ReferenceID)))
```

How can i remove all the TagReferences which contain the ReferenceID in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. EF can remove items only one by one, by clearing all loaded relations (with some special precondition) or with cascade delete where parent is deleted. If you need to delete multiple entities by some shared value you need either more complex code where you load all these entities and delete them one by one or you need to use SQL (either direct `DELETE` command or stored procedure).